# Graph of $(-1)^x$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

What would the graph of $(-1)^{x}$ look like?

I know that the value of the function alternates between $1$ and $-1$ when it is defined so I think it would just be points spread over the lines $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Is this correct? Also, will there be any definite pattern of the points.

Comment: $(-1)^x$ is a multi-valued complex number

Comment: $(-1)^x = e^{\imath x\pi}$, as Mark Comments, a complex number.  Of all real values for $x$ , only those which are integers will give $(-1)^x$ a real value.

Comment: @MarkViola what on earth is a multivalued number?  Multivalued functions, I can get behind.

Comment: @omnomnomnom Well, it is a multivalued.  And how would you denote $\log(-1)$?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it makes most sense to think of $(-1)^x$ as a complex number. One interpretation of this is to ask what the graph of $(-1)^z$ looks like in $\Bbb C$ as $z$ goes from $0$ to $1$. Since $-1=e^{i\pi}$, $(-1)^z=e^{i\pi z}$. As $z$ goes from $0$ to $1$, the value of the graph will travel along the unit circle from $1$ counter-clockwise to $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

One possible definition is
$$
(-1)^x=e^{\pi ix}=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)
$$
However, we could be equally justified to say that
$$
(-1)^x=e^{-\pi ix}=\cos(\pi x)-i\sin(\pi x)
$$
or less commonly
$$
(-1)^x=e^{3\pi ix}=\cos(3\pi x)+i\sin(3\pi x)
$$
These all are based on the fact that
$$
e^{(2k+1)\pi i}=-1
$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, all these definitions give results in the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^x$ isn't uniformly defined for values other than integers. For instance $(-1)^{(1/3)}=-1,$and$(-1)^{(1/3)}=.5+.5\sqrt3\cdot i$ But it's always true that $(-1)^x=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$. Let me know when you want me to add a proof.

Comment: The statements "$(-1)^x$ isn't uniformly defined for values other than integers" and "it's always true that $(-1)^x=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$" seem contradictory.

Comment: I get the complex numbers part, but how is $(-1)^{(1/3)}$ = -1 ?

Comment: @Internet Guy, because $(-1)^3=-1$

Comment: But how can $ (−1)^{1/3}$ = $.5 + .5√3*i $ and  $ (−1)^{1/3}$ = -1 be true simultaneously?

Comment: @InternetGuy, it's like how $1^{.5}=-1$ and $1^{.5}=1$, it's true, we've just decided that stuff works better when only the positive result is used.