# How do you graph a negative number raised to $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

As a freshman in High School, this may be a ridiculous or simple question, but what does a graph look like of something like $y=(-1)^x$? While I imagine that the graph is more or less a dotted line across $y=1$ and $y=-1$, are there are undefined points? How do fractional exponents interact with their negative subjects?

Comment: As a freshman in high school, have you learned about complex numbers yet?

Comment: I have not learned about complex numbers, so perhaps this is beyond my ken for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329298/graph-of-1x

Comment: Wolframalpha sucks at times, but for that function it will show you a nice graph with real and imaginary parts: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C+(-2)%5Ex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We normally can only graph functions that are [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), or at least close to it (perhaps with a handful of points where they are not continuous).  You will study this property in calculus.  In brief, it means that if you vary $x$ only a little, then you will vary the value $f(x)$ only a little.

The function $(-2)^x$ is not continuous, unlike the function  $2^x$.

Comment: The function _is_ continuous. It's just that it is only defined for integer $x$.

Comment: Not so; it is also defined for fractions whose reduced form has the denominator odd.

Answer (score 2):

This question is indeed tricky.

starting with the natural and integer numbers is quite easy, there you get your pattern with dots on $\{-1,1\}$.

continuing to the rationals we realize we have a problem, as $\sqrt {-1}=(-1)^{\frac12}$ is not part of the reals. However some of them are, e.g. $(-1)^3 = -1$. So you get some additional points (in fact many) wher your funciton is defined.

On all the irrational number your function is not defined, as we have the definition $a^b = e^{b\cdot \log(a)}$. Where $\log(-1)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

As others mention, this graph will have many points where it will not be defined. In any *finite* interval like $(0,1)$ there would be *infinitely* many points where this function is discontinuous.

Consider $f(x) = (-1)^{x}$  and $x = \frac{p}{q},$ where $p,q$ are mutually prime integers. Now if $q$ is even, $f(x)$ will not be **real**.